# Automation scripts: autoitscript vs ptfbpro

Tags: automation, compare, autoit

I try to use this 2 projects for primitive gui testing automation:

http://www.ptfbpro.com/

http://www.autoitscript.com/

And I can't make my choice.
Can somebody explain me: why(in 2 or 3 lines) he use one of them(or other please specify)?

Comment: PTFB Pro is a scam and the support is dead. AutoIt is free and the community is incredibly active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use **AutoIt**...

because it's **free**, **well documented** (not only) from inside of the Scite Editor and you can easily **compile your script** into a small **executable** or even create a complete **GUI** and there is a very good **community** in the forums and around here. And its **Basic-Like Syntax** is really easy to understand, there are **functions** and even a **foreach**-syntax, **dynamic arrays** and lots of **additional functions** from other users... There's good **integration** with **other programming languages** and from the use of so many **WinAPI functions** you lack of very little possibilities. It can **automate IE** usage without even displaying a browser window and send **network packages**, you can send **Keystrokes** like a user sitting in front of your screen and there's the **AU3Record** Tool which allows you to just record a Macro and replay it or save it as a script and then you can easily optimize it and edit it for your needs. Or use the **AutoIt Window Info** tool to see all the possible handlings for your application, you can **interact** with any kind of program output/display according to different algorithms you may invent.

Enough facts? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Go with Autoit3. It 's a lot more reliable, and you have a complete script language. Ptfbpro is only a tool (not free), nothing more. AUtoit3 has a lot of contributors that can help you in your process, Ptfbpro is dead.

If you want a script taht really do what you want, just go for AutoIt. Ptfbpro can't be used as a professional tool.

Answer (score 0):

Autoit3 as well.  You really can't beat it for being free and so easy to use.